# Get process name from application name and vice versa, using Applescript

Tags: applescript

On 27 February 2003, Apple employee Christopher Nebel said he'd like to straighten out [this problem](http://lists.apple.com/archives/Applescript-implementors/2003/Feb/msg00054.html) as reported by Bill Cheeseman:

> Because of the different naming for applications and application
>   processes in some circumstances, we end up having to write slightly
>   confusing scripts like this (if we've renamed Adobe Photoshop 7.0 to
>   "Photoshop" in the Finder):
>
> ```
> tell application "Photoshop" to activate
> tell application "System Events"
> tell application process "Adobe Photoshop 7.0"
> ```

Suffice it to say, it's still a problem in August 2011, and I keep running into it, so I hope the good folks here at StackOverflow can help find a workaround; thanks in advance!

Given an application name (i.e. something I can instruct to `activate`), I'd like to be able to pass that name to a subroutine to find the corresponding process name. Conversely, given a process name, I'd like to be able to pass it to a subroutine to find the corresponding application name.

Any suggestions?

Comment: One option, if given the application name, would be to activate the application and then get the process name of the frontmost process, but this seems a bit unreliable: prone to fail if the application runs in the background, or is busy, or suchlike.

Comment: I.e. as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913738/applescript-hide-get-process-name-from-app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code suffices. It draws, to some extent, upon fireshadow52's answer and upon [a post at MacScripter.net](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=36429).

```
on GetApplicationCorrespondingToProcess(process_name)
    tell application "System Events"
        set process_bid to get the bundle identifier of process process_name
        set application_name to file of (application processes where bundle identifier is process_bid)
    end tell
    return application_name
end GetApplicationCorrespondingToProcess

on GetProcessCorrespondingToApplication(application_name)
    tell application "System Events"
        set application_id to (get the id of application "Adobe Acrobat Professional" as string)
        set process_name to name of (application processes where bundle identifier is application_id)
    end tell
    return process_name
end GetProcessCorrespondingToApplication

-- Example usage:
display dialog (GetProcessCorrespondingToApplication("Adobe Acrobat Professional") as string)
display dialog (GetApplicationCorrespondingToProcess("Acrobat") as string)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
on get_application_name(this_process)
    tell application "System Events" to set the BID to (get the id of application process this_process)
    tell application "Finder" to return the name of every item of (path to applications folder) whose id is BID and kind is "Application"
end get_application_name

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

on get_process_name(this_application)
    tell application "Finder" to set the BID to (get the id of application this_application)
    tell application "System Events"
        set open_applications to (get id of every application process) as list
        return every item of open_applications whose id is BID
    end tell
end get_process_name
```

Both of these subroutines are untested, so they may not do what they're supposed to. :S

**UPDATE:** A `process` refers to an application that is already open.

Comment: No joy, I'm sorry to say. Putting the two subroutines at the start of a script, followed by the line, 'get_application_name from process "Acrobat"' gives a Syntax Error message. Putting 'my get_application_name from process "Acrobat"' inside a tell block results in Applescript Editor changing it to 'get_application_name of me from process "Acrobat"', which gives an Applescript Error message when executed: 'Can’t make application process "Acrobat" into type integer.' Putting 'get_application_name from process "Acrobat"' (experimentally) also gives an Applescript Error message.

Comment: I would try just changing both of the subroutine calls to the normail kind (i.e. `get_application_name("Acrobat")`); the fancy calls aren't really necessary.

Comment: I agree about not needing fancy calls. Still no joy, but I reckon I can probably tweak it until it works. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: No problem! That's why we're here. :)

Comment: What is the script doing that it shouldn't? Maybe I can help some more. :)

Comment: It's OK, I cracked it. Encountered some pretty odd Applescript Editor behaviour (bugs, I'm fairly sure) along the way, though!

Answer (score 2):

I find this works very well:

```
on GetApplicationCorrespondingToProcess(process_name)
  tell application "System Events"
    set application_file to file of (application processes where name is process_name)
  end tell
  return application_file
end GetApplicationCorrespondingToProcess

on GetProcessCorrespondingToApplication(application_name)
  tell application "System Events"
    set process_name to name of my application application_name
  end tell
  return process_name
end GetProcessCorrespondingToApplication

-- Example usage:
set myprocess to GetProcessCorrespondingToApplication("Terminal") as string
set myfile to GetApplicationCorrespondingToProcess(myprocess) as string
set mypath to the POSIX path of myfile -- create this just to compare to myfile
set myapp to do shell script "myval='" & myfile & "' ; echo ${myval%.app:} | awk -F':' '{print ($NF)}'"
log myprocess
log myfile
log mypath
log myapp

-- A process appears to be the name of the MacOS executable within the application.
-- Replace "Terminal" by "Firefox" to see the distinction.
-- Also, you could substitute mypath for myfile and / for : in "set myapp ...".
```